# How to move the first position of image to second position in listView on Button click in android

Tags: android, listview, button, arraylist

How to move the first position of image to second position in ListView on Button click,so that last position of image will comes to first position.

my tried codes below;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int[] images = {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5};
ArrayList<ImageModel> imageModels;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

    imageModels = new ArrayList<ImageModel> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        ImageModel imgMode = new ImageModel ();
        imgMode.setImageId (images[i]);
        imageModels.add (imgMode);
        Log.d ("chk",""+images[i]);
    }

    ListView lstView = (ListView)findViewById (R.id.lst_view);
    lstView.setAdapter (new BaseAdapterr(MainActivity.this,imageModels));

    Button btnClick = (Button)findViewById (R.id.btn_click);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
           for (int i=0 ;i < imageModels.size ();i++){
           }
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getting the object index and then use setIndex or sth like that for changing index.

Tarik.

Answer (score 0):

For a direct scroll:

```
  lstView.setSelection(0);
```

For a smooth scroll:

```
  lstView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

so your code should be following

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
           lstView.clearFocus();
           lstView.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              //int index=0; set your position
           lstView.setSelection(index);
           }
          });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your **btnClick Listener** , try it :

```
      Button btnClick = (Button)findViewById (R.id.btn_click);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
               ...

              ImageView firstImage= listView.getChiledAt(0);// get the firstimage 
              ImageView secnodImage= listView.getChiledAt(1);// get the second image
              listView.addView(firstImage,2);// we added the first image to the second index
              listView.addView(secondImage,1);// we added the second image to the first index
              myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// to refresh the view

               ...
            }
        });
```